# Document Intelligence Azure, Outcome disparities exist between the API and Studio models

Tags: python, azure, ocr

I'm using the prebuilt-layout model :

```
with open(file_path, "rb") as pdf:
    print(pdf)
    poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document(
        model_id="prebuilt-layout",
        document=pdf
    )
```

When I drop a PDF in document intelligence studio, the layout model detects more `sectionHeadings` and titles than it does through the python API.

Is there anyone who knows why these disparities exist ?

I try to use a different model, but prebuilt-document has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong API which was document analyze instead of document intelligence

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).